# How to put the div at the center with css?

Tags: html, css

I want to  put the div.father at the center of the screen,and to put the div.son at the center of the div.father.

Here is what i wanted.

[image]

How to rewrite my css code to get the result?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
<title> boxes</title>
<style type="text/css">

div.father{margin: 0 auto;width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid black;}
div.son{margin: 0 auto;width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="father">
  <div class="son"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which IE version do you need to support?

Comment: A very good article about [centering in css](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following css will make center both div.

`display:flex` and `position:absolute` will do the trick.
`align-items: center;` will center child div vertically and `justify-content: center;` will horizontally inside parent.

```css
div.father {
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 300px;
}

div.son {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="son"></div>
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6bgL2u3/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flexbox`. Add to parent `div` `display: flex` and  `justify-content: center`(for horizontal align) with `align-items: center`(for vertical align):

```css
div.father {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;/*add this*/
  justify-content: center;/*add this for horizontal align*/
  align-items: center;/*add this for vertical*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
div.son {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="son"></div>
</div>
```

Edit: For horizontal and vertical align in the middle of the screen you can use the trick described to this article [Centering Percentage Width/Height Elements](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/).

**References**

[flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Comment: To be careful with flex, all browser still used by a lot of people http://gs.statcounter.com/ not support it http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox but is a solution for futur of the humanity :)

Comment: div.father can't be at the screen center in my firefox.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```css
div.father {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:300px;
 height:300px;
 border:1px solid black;

 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
div.son {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 border:1px solid black;

 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="son"></div>
</div>
```

`position: absolute` will be place son and father out of flow. With `top` and `left` you will place item to the offset you want from the first parent with a position `absolute/relative/fixed` or `<body>` and `transform: translate(-50% -50%)` will re-center element not from top-left corner but center.

NOTE: you could use the `-moz-`, `-o-`, `-webkit-` and `-ms-` prefix before `transform` for old version browser.

```
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

You could also use `flex` to reach the same goal but if you want support all IE familly, use a polyfil for `flex`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one......

```css
html,body{
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
    }
     
    .parent{
     border:1px solid;
     width: 400px;
     height: 400px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
    
    }
    .child{
     border:1px solid;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     
     
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this property in div.father class

```
 div.father{position:relative;}
```

Add this property in div.son class

```
    div.son{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin: auto;
    }
```

This will work cross browser